# Mixture problem, basic algebra.[Serge Lang - Basic mathematics]

Tags: word-problem

**EDIT**: I've misread the question, evaluating for 10gal instead of the half and that's why my answer is two times the correct one. Sorry for that! Thanks you *Dave* for making me realize my mistake.**EndOfEDIT**

I'm currently going through Serge Lang - Basic Mathematics, so...

The problem:

The radiator of a car can contain 10 gal of liquid. If it is half full with a
mixture having 60% antifreeze and 40% water, how much more water
must be added so that the resulting mixture has only
a) 40% antifreeze?
The correct answer according to the book: $\frac{5}{2}$gal
The answer I get: 5 gal

What I do to get the answer:

**W**-watter, **A**-Antifreeze
The current mixture is 60%**A** + 40%**W**
We add more water and get mixture 40%**A** + 60%**W**

Let $x$ be the water we add.
Evaluating how much water($x$) should be added to get 60%**W** of 10+$x$(the mixture after we added the water):

$$\frac{40}{100}(10)+x=\frac{60}{100}(10+x)$$
This gives me result $x=5$.

That's how I check the result:

40%**W** + 60%**A** = 10gal (**AW**mix) = 4gal**W**+ 6gal**A**

The liquid after the water is added(10+$x$) becomes 15gal(**AW**mix).
We add 5gal**W** and get:
 4**W**+ 6**A** + 5**W** = 9**W** + 6**A**= 15gal(**AW**mix)
 60% of 15 is 9, 40% is 6. That's the amount of water and antifreeze percentage we want.

That became quite long for simple problem...
So, is there flaw in my reasoning or just a typo in the book?
Thanks in advance for any response!

Comment: So to start you have $5$gal, where the composition is $3$gal antifreeze and $2$gal water. What value $x $ satisfies $3/x=0.4$ (this will be the total amount in the tank to obtain $40%$ antifreeze)? Then simply subtract $5 $ from $x$ to get the amount of water you need to add.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!
I was going to ask from where these **5gal** come but then I've realised that I misunderstood what the problem ask for. I was reading it like "we have 10gal and that's the half of the radiator capacity, how much we should add..." It was: the radiator **can** contain, not contain.
So we start with 5gal not with 10gal as I started. 
Sorry guys for bothering you! Obviously I made a mistake.

Comment: No problem. I think the question says "half full" from $10$gal so that you check your answer at the end, to see if the amount of water you add is possible. That is, if you have to add more than $5$gal of water then it can't be done.